# Keycloak: Disable redirect to account page after password reset and show message

Tags: authentication, redirect, keycloak, forgot-password, reset-password

I am using Keycloak and I want to enable Forgot password flow. I have enabled Forgot password in login and configured SMTP to send email.
What I get out of the box from keycloak is the following

-> Click on Forgot password link -> Enter username or email -> User receives an Email with reset link -> Click on the link -> Reset password, then submit -> **User is logged in then The user is redirected to account page.**

What I want to acheive is the following

-> Click on Forgot password link -> Enter username or email -> User receives an Email with reset link -> Click on the link -> Reset password, then submit -> **Display a message saying "Your password has been updated." and do not login** the user. stay on that page.

The reason for this is, for my use-case, the user shouldn't access the account page on Keycloak.

In the authentication flow of reset credentials, I can only configure up to reset credentials.

Is there any way I can disable this action of logging in the user automatically after password reset, then redirecting to account page?

I have looked into several questions, but I cannot find an answer on how this can be achieved.

PS: I am using Keycloak docker image with a custom theme. If this can be configured using custom theme options, I have the chance to do it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @NehaM Did you find the working solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

We faced similar issue during keycloak usage and solved it via implementing custom Action Token and Action token handler ([docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_action_token_spi)). Also check out original keycloak reset credentials action token sources:

[ActionToken](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/11.0.0/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authentication/actiontoken/resetcred/ResetCredentialsActionToken.java)

[ActionTokenHandler](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/11.0.0/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authentication/actiontoken/resetcred/ResetCredentialsActionTokenHandler.java)

Try to play around `AbstractActionTokenHander.startFreshAuthenticationSession()` there several attributes that define Keycloak behaviour during reset flow like:

```
authSession.setRedirectUri(token.getNote(OIDCLoginProtocol.REDIRECT_URI_PARAM));
authSession.setAuthNote(AuthenticationManager.END_AFTER_REQUIRED_ACTIONS, "true");
authSession.setAuthNote(AuthenticationManager.SET_REDIRECT_URI_AFTER_REQUIRED_ACTIONS, "true");
authSession.setAuthNote(AuthenticationManager.END_AFTER_REQUIRED_ACTIONS, "true");
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to your keaycloak admin console, Authentication and desable "Update Profile"

Hopo it helps :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using your own client for the login page, the specified redirect, or the client default (`Base URL`) will direct where the user is sent after the password reset.

We did see that when using an admin-directed password reset, this behavior would occur (user sent to Keycloak account page).  So, we simply adjusted the `Base URL` value for the `account` client so that it points to the home page of our primarily application.

Then, after the `account` client is used to reset the password, the default redirect is to our home page.